# Ruby 分岐ごとのカウントについて

Tags: ruby

Xを変数として①の条件により+1or-1を追加していき、Xの偏りが+5or-5になったら②or③に移行する。そして②、③に移行して条件をクリアしたらリセットされてまたループするというコードを書きたいのですがうまくいきません。
ここまでは雰囲気で書いたのですが思い通りに動いてくれません、いい方法ありませんか？よろしくお願いします。

loop do
X = 0
---------------------------------------------①
if ほげほげ
X = X - 1
elsif ほげほげ
X = X + 1
--------------------------------------------------②
if X > 5
X = X - 5
------------------------------------------------- ③ 
if X < -5
X = X + 5

end

Comment: `X`の初期化はloopの外でやるべきではないでしょうか？　それから`ほげほげ`はループ中に何らかの要因で変更される条件が指定されるという理解で良いですか？　例えば`あるファイルが存在するか`とか`あるIPにpingを送ると正常に返ってくる`とかが思いつきましたが。

Comment: 擬似コードではなく実際のコードを記載してください。コードを記載するときはコードブロックとしてマークアップしてください。コードの部分を選択してCtrl+Kか、エディタの上に表示されている"{}"のボタンです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qiita.com/timutimusan/items/583791dc5680cb6f12d1

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11182148301

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/100798

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄で指摘されている通り、Xをループ内で初期化してしまうとループが戻ってくる度にXが0に初期化されてしまうため上手くいかないので、Xの初期化はループの外で行いましょう。
また、Xの値が+5, -5になったら0にするには、Xの絶対値が5ならば0にするという式に単純化できそうです。(rubyはif文を後ろに書くことが出来る。if修飾子と呼ばれるもの)

```
X = 0
loop do
  if hoge
    X = X + 1
  elsif fuga
    X = X - 1
  end

  X = 0 if X.abs == 5
end
```

余談ですが、質問文のコードにはif文の対になるendが存在しないため、大変読みづらいです。